# cannot install wine on 17.1 mint: unmet dependencies, broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, wine

I have a Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca - Release amd64 20141126]/ trusty contrib main non-free installed, and the **apt-get install wine** wont do the trick. it returns the following:

*Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*

then I tried everything I found on this thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

I disabled, and removed all ppa-s.

still I cannot install wine (nor skype)

Comment: when i run **sudo apt-get -f install** i get this: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
so it means that it fails.

Comment: as the link in the original post shows, i followed those steps. sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get autoclean, sudo apt-get -f install, sudo dpkg --configure -a, the sudo apt-get -f install again. then with **sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade** it upgrades, end then apt-get -f install seems to exit with **0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded** then id think its all good again, but it still cannot apt-get install wine. gives the message as in the original post.

Comment: **sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade** produces this: *Calculating upgrade... Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.*

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to install skype, do this with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install skype`!

maybe you should have read the [release notes](http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rebecca_mate.php) first!
if you're experiencing issues with skype on a 64bit-system, also install ia32-libs: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ia32-libs` would do this for you.

Comment: **sudo apt-get install skype** does this in my terminal:
*Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*

Comment: now i've tested it and `sudo apt-get install skype` worked like a charm! it looks like you have messed up your package-management-system...! -- you can try something like this: `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` and then install skype.